# Running Time of BFS vs Dijkstra

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

I have a unweighted, connected graph G with n vertices and m edges.
m=O(n log n).
I want to find the shortest path from vertex s to vertex v.
I want to know if a BFS traversal or Dijkstra's algorithm would be asymptotically faster.

BFS would start from s.
Dijkstra's algorithm, starts from s, and implements a Fibonacci heap.

The running time of BFS is Θ(n+m) = O(n+n log n) = O(n log n)
And the running time of Dijkstra is O(m+n log n) = O(n log n+n log n) = O(n log n)

So are both algorithms, for this problem, asymptotically as fast, or am i missing something?

Comment: Dijkstra and BFS are the same algorithms if executed on an unweighted graph. The rest are just implementation details which are unspecified in the algorithms. And on a weighted graph, BFS can not find a shortest path but just _a path_, in which case the comparison is weird.

Comment: You have found an upper bound for both -- O(n log n), and concluded that the running times are the same. But your reasoning is wrong and you've drawn a false conclusion. For example, for trees dijkstra runs in Theta(n log n) time, and BFS runs in Theta(n) time (for trees, m=n-1 which is in O(n log n)).

Comment: @Paul, please note that the question sets out with m=O(nlogn).

Comment: @trincot It's hard to say exactly what "m = O(n log n)" means -- can you define it exactly? Perhaps something like "there's a c>0 such that for all graphs we consider, then the number of edges (m) is always less than c * n log n where n is the number of vertices.". But that includes very sparse graphs, for which BFS outperforms Dijkstra aysmptotically (for example, the subset of trees).

Comment: Let's ask the Author to define what they mean ;-). In my understanding trees would be excluded from that.

Comment: @trincot In the language of this question, I would say BFS is asymptotically faster when m = o(n log n), and BFS and dijkstra are asymptotically the same speed when m=Theta(n log n).

Comment: @Paul, we agree on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given properties of the unweighted graph:

- (,) is connected, and
- || ∈ θ(||log||)

...we can indeed derive a time complexity of (||) for both BFS and Dijkstra's algorithm with Fibonacci heap.

#### Just an additional note:

The phrase *"asymptotically as fast"* does not mean that there is an input size above which both algorithms will run just as fast. It means that for large enough inputs the *ratio* of their running times (on the same computer) will remain within a constant min/max range.

As Fibonacci heaps have quite some overhead and BFS just needs a simple queue or two arrays, there is no doubt that this bounded ratio will be in favor of BFS.